# Books to help us to draw 3D pictures

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, online-resources

I will begin to teach calculus and topology in a college and I would like to know if there are some books or sites which teach us to draw 3D pictures as torus, möbius band, etc.

I saw some mathematicians which can draw difficult pictures by hand on blackboard as möbius band very well. I thought maybe they learn from somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect Mathematica, as I have seen some nice examples on this site.

Comment: @copper.hat no, you didn't follow my question. I would like to draw these pictures _myself_  in order to draw them on blackboard.

Comment: Do you mean draw by hand?

Comment: @JasperLoy yes, as I said above.

Comment: This is a question about art then.

Comment: Ah, then there is nothing to answer. Just draw.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm looking for sites or books which teach how to draw them. I saw some mathematicians which can draw difficult pictures as möbius band very well. I thought maybe they learn from somewhere.

Comment: Related: [Handbook of mathematical drawing?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613158/handbook-of-mathematical-drawing/)

Comment: I don't think such a resource exists. The "trick" lies in knowing which features of an object are important to characterize it (at least for the task at hand) and in a bit of practice.